# send multiple packets of data using python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

So now I have a server and client script. I'm trying to upload a file from the client to the server. However, the data from the file in the client will be cut out by the HEADER size. How do I send multiple packets under the same send command to the server?

server.py:

```
import socket
import threading
HEADER=2048
PORT=5050
SERVER=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR=(SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT='utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE='!DISCONNECT'
SEPARATOR='<SEPERATE>'
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
def handle_client(conn,addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')
    connected=True
    while connected:
        data=conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if data==DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connected=False
        else:
            data=data.split(SEPARATOR)
            file=open(data[0],'w')
            file.write(data[1])
            print('file received')
            conn.send('file received'.encode(FORMAT))         
    conn.close()
    print(f'[DISCONNECT] {addr} disconnected')

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn,addr=server.accept()
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}')
print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
HEADER=2048
PORT=5050
FORMAT='utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE='!DISCONNECT'
SEPARATOR='<SEPERATE>'
SERVER=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR=(SERVER,PORT)
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
def send(msg):
    message=msg.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT))
file=open('question_pool.csv','r')
data=file.read()
send(f'question_pool.csv{SEPARATOR}{data}')
file.close()
send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

Comment: It is **important** to remember that TCP is a STREAM protocol, not a PACKET protocol.  Just because you send writes of 80, 120, and 60, does not mean the other side will receive them that way.  It might receive one buffer of 260.  It might receive 13 reads of 20.  Your server has to handle that.  That's why you need a signal for "done".

Answer (score 1):

In short, you want to send multiple chunks of any file that is larger than your `HEADER` size. Split the file into chunks smaller than the `HEADER` size, and send each chunk individually. Then when all the chunks are set, send a message that says the whole file has been sent so that the server can save it.

Here is my code for the solution described above:
`server.py`:

```py
import socket
import threading


HEADER = 2048
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'
SEPARATOR = '<SEPERATE>'
FILE_FINISHED_SENDING = '<!FILE_SENT!>'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')
    connected = True
    current_file = None

    while connected:
        data = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if data == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connected = False
        elif data == FILE_FINISHED_SENDING:
            current_file.close()
            current_file = None
            conn.send(b'file received.')
        else:
            data = data.split(SEPARATOR)
            if len(data) == 2 and data[1] == '':
                # The name of the file was sent, more will follow.
                current_file = open(data[0], 'w')
                conn.send(b'filename recieved')
            else:
                # File data was send, so write it to the current file
                current_file.write(data[1])
                print('chunk of file recv''d')
                conn.send(b'chunk received')
    conn.close()
    print(f'[DISCONNECT] {addr} disconnected')



def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}')


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

`client.py`:

```py
import socket
from pathlib import Path

HEADER = 2048
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'
SEPARATOR = '<SEPERATE>'
FILE_FINISHED_SENDING = '<!FILE_SENT!>'
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def chunker(string: str, size: int):
    return (string[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(string), size))


def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT))


def send_file(filepath: str):
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding=FORMAT) as f:
        data = f.read()

    first_bits = f'{Path(filepath).name}{SEPARATOR}'  # Easy way of getting just a file's name from its path
    send(first_bits)  # Send the filename to the server
    for chunk in chunker(data, HEADER-48):  # Leave a safe buffer
        # Send each chunk of the file
        send(f"{SEPARATOR}{chunk}")

    # Tell the server that's all for this file.
    # Now it can close the file object.
    send(FILE_FINISHED_SENDING)


send_file("/path/to/file.html")
send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

#### Tips:

- make sure that your special messages like `SEPARATOR`, `FILE_FINISHED_SENDING` and `DISCONNECT_MESSAGE` are NOT going to appear in the files you are sending. Otherwise things might get wonky.
- You may want to read files as raw bytes when you send them through the socket, instead of reading as strings, encoding, decoding, *etc.* This way you could send binary files such as `.mp3`, for example.